# How to efficiently merge cells in Excel using a macro?

Tags: excel

I am trying to develop an index, but in order to make correct calculations and pivot tables, I need to merge some cells. Doing this manually would take a lot of time, therefore I am looking for a more efficient way. I assume a Macro might help me out here, yet I do not really know how to get started.

A bit of context on the datasheet: The info in cells E until AB was used to calculate the numbers in cells AC, AD, AE and AF. This information was hided as these cells do not need to be merged.

I am in the need of a macro that:

- Merges the value in column A when the organization name is identical.
- Merges the information in columns AC, AD, AE and AF when it refers to the same organization in column A.

Can somebody help me out? Thank you in advance for the help!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LShf3.png

This should be a result, but then accomplished with a macro so that it can be done efficiently for larger lists:https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm4RQ.png

Comment: "Merges the value in column A when the organization name is identical."? add the results? Take the largest? Calculate the average? what precisely do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: The cells need to be merged when the Organization name is identical

Comment: So? that's obvious. BUT still what do you **mean** by "merge"?

Comment: I have added an image showing what I would like to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub SubMerge()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngName As Range
    Dim RngFirstCat As Range
    Dim DblTotalCat As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngName = Range("A2")
    Set RngFirstCat = Range("AC2")
    DblTotalCat = 4
    
    'Deactivating display alerts.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Repeat until an empty cell is found.
    Do Until RngName.Value = ""
        
        'Repeat until a different value is found.
        Do Until RngName.Offset(1, 0).Cells(RngName.Cells.Count, 1).Value <> RngName.Cells(1, 1).Value
            
            'Increasing the size of RngName by 1 row.
            Set RngName = RngName.Resize(RngName.Rows.Count + 1)
            
        Loop
        
        'Checking if RngName has more than 1 row.
        If RngName.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            
            'Setting RngFirstCat.
            Set RngFirstCat = Cells(RngName.Row, RngFirstCat.Column).Resize(RngName.Rows.Count)
            
            'Covering each category.
            For DblCounter01 = DblTotalCat - 1 To 0 Step -1
                
                'Merging the cells.
                RngFirstCat.Offset(0, DblCounter01).Merge
                
            Next
        End If
        
        'Setting RngName for the next value.
        Set RngName = RngName.Cells(1, 1).Offset(RngName.Cells.Count)
        
    Loop
    
    'Deactivating display alerts.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub
```